# Sketch the phase flow for this system $\dot r = (1-r^2)\cosh(r)$ , $\dot \theta = 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polar-coordinates

I am given the system $\\$ $\dot r = (1-r^2)\cosh(r)$, $\dot \theta = 1$ and am required to sketch the phase flow for it in both Cartesian co-ordinates $(x,y) = (r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta)$ and also polar co-ordinates $(r,\theta)$

So I know I need to solve differential equations which give me

$\theta = t + c$ where $c$ is a constant

but I am struggling to solve the other differential equation as separating the variable does not work, as the integration is difficult to solve.

$$\dfrac {dr}{(1-r^2)\cosh(r)} = 1 \cdot dt$$

Solving the differential equation is the only thing stopping me drawing the phase flow, but I am really struggling on how to solve it.

Comment: Since $\cosh(r)>0$ it is easy to plot the flows. The critical value is $r=1$. When $r<1$, $r$ increases and when $r>1$, $r$ decreases i.e. there is a stable limit cycle in the $(x,y)$ plane and a stable limit line in the $(r,\theta)$ plane.

Comment: @ctnt Ah right, so I'm not really concerned with solving the differential equation. I'll attempt this and let you know how I get on

Comment: @CTNT I've tried to understand what you're saying, and looked at other examples but I'm still struggling with this Q

Answer (score 0):

The above analysis in my comment shows that there is a stable limit cycle defined by $r=1$ i.e. all trajectories converge asymptotically towards this cycle. If we transform the system equation to cartesian coordinates we get
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-y+(1-x^2-y^2)\cosh(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\
\frac{dy}{dt}=x+(1-x^2-y^2)\cosh(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

with [streamplot](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=streamplot%5B%7B-y%2B%281-x%5E2-y%5E2%29cosh%28sqrt%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%29x%2Fsqrt%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%2Cx%2B%281-x%5E2-y%5E2%29cosh%28sqrt%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%29y%2Fsqrt%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%7D%2C%20%7Bx%2C-2%2C2%7D%2C%20%7By%2C-2%2C2%7D%5D)
showing in the following Figure which is as expected.

[image: Stream plot]

I suppose you can now complete the flow in the $(r,\theta)$ plane.